# Symfony crawler selectButton method can't get form

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit

here is my html

```
<form  name="station" method="post" action="/stations/new" role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label required" for="station_name">Name</label>
     <input type="text" id="station_name" name="station[name]" required="required" maxlength="255" class="form-control" >
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="station_active">
        <input type="checkbox" id="station_active" name="station[active]" value="1" />Active</label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <button type="submit" id="station_submit" name="station[submit]" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" id="station__token" name="station[_token]" class="form-control" value="aze123aze" >
</form>
```

i want to get my form using the crawler. I tried the selectButton method like this

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('station[submit]')->form(array());
```

but i get the error : `InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.`

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I have no enough rating to just write a comment instead of put it in the answer.

So, could you please show how are you getting $crawler? Problem might be:

- $crawler not point to DOM which contains this form
- this form appears on page after some java script actions(Ajax for example), but not sure that this is your case.

Comment: ok just fixed it i'm quite retarded and forgot to then the crawler after a $client->click($link); ... you still get your vote and accept answer :P

Answer (score 0):

The `selectButton` method accept the value The button text. So Try with:

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Ajouter')->form(array());
```

Hope this help

Comment: @RomMer very strange. Some time the domparser doesn't work if the html is not well formed (some closed tags etc). Is the HTML autogenerated by symfony or handmade?

Comment: the form is generated by symfony